# can radius and degree exist in the same angle

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I and my teacher had an argument about the result of $\sin(\pi-1)$.

He said that to convert the angle from radius to degree you must replace every $\pi$ with 180 so he said that $\sin(\pi-1)=\sin(180-1)=\sin(179)$. but I think that $\pi$ is a value so $\pi-1$ must be evaluated first which $\simeq$ 2.14159
the convert it to degree by multiplying by $\frac{180}{\pi}$ which $\simeq$ 122.7.

So I'm confused should I treat $\pi$ as Radius and 1 as Degree or they must be the same unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They must be the same unit. Your approach is perfectly all right. In case of angles, you must treat $(\pi - 1)$ as radian wholly or degree wholly (although I have not seen $\pi^\circ$ in any book till now).

Answer (score 1):

Your rendering appears correct to me.

Having said that, there may be some additional context which explains why your professor advised you this way.

Ultimately, we can't provide a definitive answer to questions of the form, "[So'n'so says X and I say Y. Who's right?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21525/266049)" These questions are best resolved with "So'n'so."

Plug the equation into a physical or online calculator that allows for the full expression to be seen with it's result. Choose degrees mode and then radians mode. Discuss the results with your professor.

It *could* be that what your professor is trying to communicate is the necessity of keeping a single unit in the parentheses.

Only a discussion with your professor can identify any potential misunderstanding.

Comment: so you're saying that $\pi$ and 1 can be in different units in the same angle ?

Comment: You've either got $\pi$ degrees minus 1 degree (unlikely, in my experience), or $\pi$ radians minus 1 radian, as you suggested. The latter is more likely, and I doubt that I have *ever* seen the units mixed in the way described.

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb is to forget about unit issues and just define

$$º:=\frac{\pi}{180} .$$

PS: This makes you right, by the way.